# com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this issue when I am trying to run my project -

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process .gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-analytics-impl-11.8.0.aar\0e3311be69809df8820438f9666651f5\jars\classes.jar
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
>   com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete 
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcku`.
>
> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process Firebase-analytics-impl-11.8.0.aar\jars\classes.jar

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 171312
        versionName "1.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        project.archivesBaseName = "doctor"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles fileTree(dir: "proguard", include: ["*.pro"]).asList().toArray()
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles fileTree(dir: "proguard", include: ["*.pro"]).asList().toArray()
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "environment"
    productFlavors {
        staging {
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        }
        production {
        }
        development {
            applicationIdSuffix ".development"
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

ext {
    retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'
    firebaseVersion = '15.0.2'
}
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation project(path: ':quickblox')
}
```

build.gradle of QuickBlox module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    defaultPublishConfig "doctorDebug"
    publishNonDefault true
    productFlavors {
        doctor {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DOCTOR", "true"
            versionNameSuffix "-doctor"
        }
        patient {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DOCTOR", "false"
            versionNameSuffix "-patient"
        }
    }
    android {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.8.1'
    api('com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:3.8.1')
}
```

I have added this `android.enableD8.desugaring = true` in `gradle.properties`. Still, I am facing the same issue.

Any solution?

Comment: is multidexEnabled on your project?

Comment: Yes .multidexEnabled in project.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I have added build.gradle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please add this dependency also

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
```

Hope this issue will be fixed.

Comment: What led you conclude that this is the reason? I have this dependency in my project and I am still having this error.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much.

This was also happening for this issue in tipsi-stripe. At least, for me, it solved it:

https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/issues/504